# jquery mobile and dialog with splitview script installed

Tags: jquery-mobile, dialog

I found this script on the net... and I wanted to add a simple dialog on the star on the top-right corner but I can't make it works.

already tried with the code below(line 118 main.html)

```
<td rowspan="2"><div><a href="foo.html" data-rel="dialog"><img src="img/star.png" /></a></div></td>
```

obviously I already created the foo.html page... but until now No luck!!!

here where you can found the code...

http://espediasap.espedia.it:8080/PrototipoDDP/main.html

I hope that someone will help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this example:

**PAGE A**

```
<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="content">
        <a href="B.html" data-icon="star" data-iconpos="right" data-role="button" data-rel="dialog">Goto B page</a>
    </div>

</div>
```

**PAGE B**

```
<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="content">
        <h3>Page B</h3>
    </div>

</div>
```